# Why does scipy curve_fit and statsmodel WLS give different results when weighted

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, statsmodels, least-squares

To my understanding, Statsmodel WLS (weighted least squared) and curve_fit (which uses least-squares by default) should provide the same outcome.

When using non weighted values, it does (code below #1). However, when I used weights, the output values become totally different (code below #2).

Why is this?

_ #1 non weighted

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


Y = [-5,2,3,4,5,6,7]
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
W = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

def equation_func (x, m, c):
    return m * x + c     

popt, pcov = curve_fit(equation_func,X, Y,  p0=[-1.6, 1.28], sigma=[1 / w for w in W], 
                                         absolute_sigma=True)

curve_results = [equation_func(x, popt[0], popt[1]) for x in X]


wls_model = sm.WLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X), weights=W)
results = wls_model.fit()
print(results.params)
print([popt[1], popt[0]])
#WLS - [-3.42857143  1.64285714]
#Curve_fit - [-3.42857143, 1.64285714]
```

_#2 Weighted

```
Y = [-5,2,3,4,5,6,7]
X = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
W = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def equation_func (x, m, c):
    return m * x + c     

popt, pcov = curve_fit(equation_func,X, Y,  p0=[-1.6, 1.28], sigma=[1 / w for w in W], 
                                         absolute_sigma=True)


curve_results = [equation_func(x, popt[0], popt[1]) for x in X]


wls_model = sm.WLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X), weights=W)
results = wls_model.fit()
print(results.params)
print([popt[1], popt[0]])
#WLS - [-1.64285714  1.28571429]
#Curve_fit - [-0.5840336134466501, 1.0966386554667582]
```

Comment: use `wls_model = sm.WLS(Y,sm.add_constant(X), weights=np.asarray(W)**2)` In curve_fit it has the interpretation of standard deviation, in statsmodels is is base on variance

Comment: @Josef: It would be nice to have your comment available as an answer (if nothing else for those of us that look for unanswered questions).